# Spring boot service registry

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-consul

What is the difference between Consul and Eureka service registry? Is consul capable of load balancing? Is it better to migrate from eureka to consul? If yes what benefits I'll get?

I'm trying to migrate my project to springboot 3 , but not sure about service registry already I'm using eureka but project team advised to use consul?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally depends on your need. If you need easy setup with **spring-cloud** and your project requires **mid-level load balancing** then you can go with eureka service. If you need **high-level load balancing** and **more scalability** then you can go with **Consul**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project specification. consul has a other features such as configuration management which means you can put your properties in consul and update the configuration, and it can be applied to your application without restart.
Load balancing can be implemented through consul too.
below is some of key features of Hashicorp Consul:

- Service Registry & Discovery
- External Configuration
- Proxy